# How to find the sum given n, 1st score and last score?

Tags: excel, statistics

Lets say you have a column called "values" and "no.of times". You have thousands of rows but you don't want to scrape the data from the site.. You have to calculate the sum of value column all u have is N = Total no.of persons (total Rows = last row value), 1st row value and last row value. How would you make a framework where you will get an approximate sum of values with these parameters given? You can use excel and some stats knowledge?

```
Rank. Score No.of times 
1        2000 4
2.       4000 6 
3        8000 7 

N = 3 
1st rank score = 2000 
Last rank score = 8000
Total = 8000+4000+2000=14000
```

Since it's for 3 rows it was easier to calculate but what if you have 1million rows and you don't have the data in an excel sheet or anywhere else. I just want a framework where I can arrive near around 14000 by just knowing
N, 1st rank score and last rank score.

Comment: You should add a data example and expected output

Comment: Yes, I did that. Now can you understand my question?

Comment: so you got a bunch of cells and you want to get which N cells grouping sums around 14.000 and from those N cells you need to know highest rank value and lowest rank value. I'm not sure if that can be achieved in Excel, to be honest. Let's hope somebody else can help you out

Comment: No... I just want the approximate value for total cells because in this situation we don't know the values of the cells in between